# Getting a "list object not callable" error when trying to convert from hex to binary

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I am trying to write a code that takes a file with data points in hex and convert them to binary. I need to check that the 2nd entry point of the converted binary is a valid point (equal to 1). If all four converted binary are valid I then move that line to a new file

```
f = open("valid.txt","w+")

with open('pz_muon_halflife.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
    col = 1
    for line in csv_reader:
        while col <=5:
            if col == 5:
                f.write(f'{" ".join(line)}')
            else:
                check = bytes.fromhex[{line(col)}] #converts the hex in the column to binary (error here)
                if check[:2] == 1: #checks to see if the 3rd entry is valid
                    col += 1 #resets col to 1
                else: #value is invalid
                    col = 6 #sets column to 6 so that the while loop ends
        col = 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')

f.close()
```

Comment: You might want to check out python binascii module, the specific API will depend on what the input is

Comment: Everything is all clear now

Answer (score 0):

Assume `line[col]` is a hex string, e.g. "DEADBEEF", you should write that line as:

```
check = bytes.fromhex(line[col])
```

Comment: it is now giving me the error "fromhex() argument must be str, not set"

Comment: any chance you can print `repr(line[col])` right before that line?

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be the line

```py
check = bytes.fromhex[{line(col)}]
```

`line` is a list so to index into it you need to use `[]`, e.g. `line[col]`.

Furthermore, `fromhex` is a function, so it should be `bytes.fromhex(line[col])`. I am not sure why you have the curly braces around `line[col]` since that would give you a set and `fromhex` would throw an error.

**NOTE** If you want to get from hex to binary, a simple solution (in Python3) is

```py
check = bin(int(line[col], 16))
```

This converts the hex string to a corresponding hex integer and then calling `bin` on it turns it into a binary string which will give you what you need.

Comment: it now gives an error on the same line stating "list index out of range"

Comment: That means your `line` list only has one element. Are you sure the line `col += 1` is doing what you intend to do? That is incrementing `col` and not resetting it to 1.

You seem to be very new to Python so I highly recommend figuring out the basic workings of python data structures. :)

Comment: Yes I had to teach myself because my school doesn't give introductory course for Python but requires me to know it for projects in later classes